# Malware Real-Time Memory Analysis

Tags: memory, analysis, malware

I'm attempting to analyze some malware. As you'd expect, the malware can get a bit complicated in what it does. I believe I've discovered the approximate time where it utilizes an AES key prior to deleting the key (from memory). Because this happens so quick, I don't have the time to core dump the process to find the decryption key.

My question is, how should I go about watching all memory reads (or more importantly writes) on the system? Yes, i know that's a lot. However, between knowing a small time window (second or two), and understanding that the key will have to have a given format, i think it's possible to narrow down possible keys to a reasonable key space.

EDIT: Sadly, there has been many concerns raised already about this question regarding the asking for a tool. Let's make this perfectly clear. I AM NOT ASKING FOR A TOOL RECOMMENDATION. :-) Similarly, if there are other censoring concerns please feel free to raise them and I can redact my question further.

Comment: Please review the [help/on-topic] guidelines. Questions asking us to find or recommend a tool, library, software product, book, or other off-site resource are specifically indicated as being off-topic here.

Comment: Edited post to reflect that I'm not actually asking about tools. I'm asking about how to do that. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: OK. Update my close reason as well to "Too broad". :-) (You forgot to remove *a kernel level tool or something that can watch*, which are still tool sor software as well.)

Comment: Interesting. Because that piece of text is referring to a technique that would then be implemented as a tool. But i suppose when you make the rules you can do what you want.

Comment: Updated again. I'm guessing you're only here for procedural concerns regarding this question. If there are concerns about this version, please let me know :-). And of course if you'd like to propose a solution or say something relevant to the question, that would be acceptable as well.